# cucumber-messages.ndjson persists after cypress run with cucumber-preprocessor and reporting is completed

Tags: cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am running cypress with this in package.json:

```js
{
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
"filterSpecs": true,
"json": {
  "enabled": true,
  "output": "./test/report/cucumber_report.json",
  "formatter": "./bin/cucumber-json-formatter-linux"
},
  "messages": {
    "enabled": true
},
"stepDefinitions": [
  "e2e/hello-world/**/*.{js,ts}",
  "e2e/[filepath].{js,ts}"
]
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^15.0.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.15.0",
    "cypress": "^11.2.0",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.5.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  }
```

a script uses multiple-cucumber-html-reporter to produce the html report:

```js
const report = require('multiple-cucumber-html-reporter');

report.generate({
    jsonDir: './test/report',
    reportPath: './test/report/html',
});
```

The tests are running fine and producing a report and json correctly, but the cucumber-messages.ndjson is also persisting:

```html
.
|-- cucumber-html-report.js
|-- cucumber-messages.ndjson
|-- cypress.config.ts
|-- package-lock.json
|-- package.json
|-- test
|   `-- report
|       |-- cucumber_report.json
|       `-- html
// and plenty of good html stuff
|           `-- index.html
```

Am I missing an option to remove it?
I can delete it after the report is produced, but I expected an option should do that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages (ndjson) report is implicitly generated, as the json and html report are products of it (think a function - messages goes in - json and html comes out). Hence, if either is enabled, then messages are too. You can control the location of this implicitly generated report the same way  you do with the other types.

With the introduction of a more stateful backend in v17.0.0 however, one might think that the backend could contain this implicit state without touching the file system. I've put this on my todo-list.

Comment: thanks - will rm the file in the meantime. Thinking about it - changing the location should be understood by the dependent prcoesses, right?

Comment: Sure. You know how you specify the location of the JSON reports? You can specify the location of the messages report as well, like shown below.

<pre>
{
  "messages": {
    "output": ".."
  },
  "json": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "..."
  }
}
</pre>

Comment: I don't know how SO comments or code formatting works. Anyone who does should feel free to edit my above-comment.